# Making basic requests in JS to my Rails API from Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, api

I'm writing a Chrome extension which I want to talk to my Rails API.

A `user` has an `email` and `password` to it.

Right now my `users_controller` looks like this:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    if @user.save
      render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user
    else
      render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

And in the Chrome console, I'm testing some create actions like

`$.post('http://localhost:3000/users', "me@example.com");`

Which return:

```
{
user: {
created_at: "2013-04-27T18:11:57Z",
email: null,
id: 2,
password: null,
updated_at: "2013-04-27T18:11:57Z"
}
}
```

Any suggestions on how to hit my API and create a new user?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to provide a JavaScript object with key/value pairs representing the attributes of the User model you want to construct on the server. Try this:

```
$.post('http://localhost:3000/users', {email: "me@example.com"});
```

**Edit:** If you do not have [parameter wrapping](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html) enabled in your Rails controller, you will need to explicitly wrap the parameters you send in the POST request with the `user` key:

```
$.post('http://localhost:3000/users', {user: {email: "me@example.com"}});
```

Comment: I keep getting email: null and password: null when I look at the JSON of /users in my browser. Any idea why?

Comment: You may not have parameter wrapping turned on in your controller. Can you paste in your controller code and show the "params" hash contents from your console output?

Comment: The controller code is in the post above, that's the entirety of the create action in Rails

Comment: But is there a `wrap_parameters` anywhere in the project? And again, what is your `params` Hash output from the Rails console? I am suspecting that `params[:user]` is not getting populated with the User attributes such as `:email:

Comment: There isn't any `wrap_parameters` in my project. `params[:user]` definitely isn't getting populated with the right content in the right format.

Comment: You need to either enable parameter wrapping (see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html) or else wrap your JSON parameters in another JavaScript object for the key `user`. I've amended my answer to include that, please upvote and/or mark as accepted if that works for you.